# HTML accordion without js orJQuery

Tags: html

I would be needing help in using accordion. I want to create an accordion only using HTML. No javascript of jQuery. I would want to know how to make it work. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

In the below code, by default I want only the table header to be displayed and on click of the checkbox I would want the rows below to be populated. Any pointers as to how this can be done using HTML only.

```
 <table border="1">
       <tr>
         <th><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
         <th>Multiple Rows </th>
         <th>Ratings</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
         <td>First Check </td>
         <td>1</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/></td>
         <td>Second Check </td>
         <td>2</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
</table>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use Pure CSS3 accordian http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/pure-css3-accordion/

Comment: Jatin, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @RacerNerd I see you deleted your answer before I had time to downvote it! :)

Comment: @RacerNerd A link to a website is not an answer, he was right to leave a comment. The OP should have Googled it himself first anyway.

Comment: Whew!!  This hand flew out of my computer and slapped me.

Comment: @Jatin Could you give me guidelines as to how to use this approach for checkbox event? I do not want the hover over option. I am looking to display the content of the table on click of a checkbox else should just display the header of the table.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in a way that is useable on touch screens would be to misuse CSS. You would be looking for a "pure css accordion menu"

Examples

[codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/21/accordion-with-css3/)
[codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/pure-css3-accordion/6513680)
[designshack](http://designshack.net/articles/css/build-a-freaking-awesome-pure-css-accordion/)

The idea behind all of them is using a hidden input button (either radio or checkbox) and toggling styles based on its state.

In general - don't do this. its neat, but it is pretty much a hack.

Comment: the link in @Jatin's comment seems to be able to do it without a "hack", but that one doesn't let you do it by clicking (only hover), but I would definitely consider that in your answer and edit it accordingly instead of just saying you have to use the hacky way

Comment: Hovers are really usable in mobile phones, so I tend to ignore hover only solutions (though I totally understand that - and am jealous of - others don't have to be). As a result, the input style is really the only cross-platform way of achieving it, which involves using css in a way that it is in no way intended to be. hence my use of the term hack.

Comment: "And as he stared at the computer without a good comeback, he decided he would upvote the answer"

Comment: :] - updated to be more clear. Thank you for grounding me, Markassoftware.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. After following Jatin's link above I would like some directions as to how this accordion can be done for just a table. Instead of hover over I want the expand option to take place on the click of radio button. Can this be done using HTML display tags? Any pointers on how to get there will be appreciated.  @Patrick